# Adding a summary table to facet grid box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a table that summarizes the info I have in a facet grid boxplot to the same plot.

```
df<- structure(list(design = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "SR", "SR", "SR", "SR", "SR"
), Species = c("LMB", "LMB", "BLG", "BLG", "BLG", "BLG", "LMB", 
"BLG", "LMB", "BLG", "LMB", "LMB", "LMB", "BLG", "BLG", "LMB", 
"BLG", "BLG", "LMB"), Value = c(10.9673144080207, 9.69716158252908, 
13.6176455626267, 12.5184221861068, 7.07161082124456, 26.6081334130079, 
4.83476200538245, -2.44881629932982, 1.63297655884495, 18.8302775817964, 
6.8889811208883, 4.6387733793561, 7.56071784901834, -26.3109417867886, 
27.4553930399756, -3.19241479249914, -9.65440732501407, 40.3505935270246, 
2.9681096231288), season = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Spring", 
"Fall"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

ggplot(df, aes(x=design, y=Value))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  stat_summary(fun = mean, shape=21, size=1, fill='red', col='red', geom='point')+
  #geom_jitter(alpha = 0.09, width = 0.2)+
  facet_grid(season ~ Species)+
  ylab("Relative Bias (RB%)")+
  xlab("Design")+
   theme_light()
```

I want to add the following summed mean values across observations into a table and to the right of  the plot:

```
table<- structure(list(indicator = c("total_spring", "total_fall"), season = c("Spring", 
"Fall"), f = c("22", "15"), h = c("1.9", "23.1"), r = c("-6.1", 
"13"), sr = c("9", "-8")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)) # numbers are made up for example, not representative of data in boxplots
```

I've tried a couple of solutions using `plotrix` and `ggpmisc`, but had no luck. Ideally, this table would just take the place of another column added to the grid. Wondering if this might just be easiest with `gridExtra` and adding them together as separate objects? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with patchwork and gridExtra:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(gridExtra)

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x=design, y=Value))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  stat_summary(fun = mean, shape=21, size=1, fill='red', col='red', geom='point')+
  facet_grid(season ~ Species)+
  ylab("Relative Bias (RB%)")+
  xlab("Design")+
  theme_light()

# use gridExtra to turn the table into a Grob
table <- tableGrob(table)

# plot side by side with patchwork, control relative size with `widths` and `heights` arguments
gg + table +
  plot_layout(widths = c(5, 7),
              heights = c(5, 3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Came up with this same answer just after I posted the question. Appreciate the help!

Comment: That's often the way!

Answer (score 2):

There's many ways, e.g. using `cowplot`, if your plot is `p`:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(cowplot)

table_grob <- tableGrob(table, rows = NULL)

ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(p, width = 0.6) +
  draw_grob(table_grob, x = 0.6, width = 0.4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I haven't used cowplot before but seems like this would also work really well in addition to Peter's answer. Thanks for your response!